# bootstrap Responsive navbar hidden parts not going into button

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here is the code for navbar

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">

          <!-- .btn-navbar is used as the toggle for collapsed navbar content -->
          <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </a>

          <!-- Be sure to leave the brand out there if you want it shown -->
          <a class="brand" href="index.html">EasyUniv</a>



          <!-- Everything you want hidden at 940px or less, place within here -->
          <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
              <ul class="nav">
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="index.html">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="campus.html">Campus</a></li>
                <li><a href="advertise.html">Advertise</a></li>
              </ul>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

The example is at: www.easyuniv.com/staging

when you make the screen smaller it hides the nav buttons correctly but they do not go into the little drop down like it should. also at certain widths there is weird padding.. been trying different things and can't get these to work.

Thanks

Comment: There's an error coming up in my js console. Have you set up the scripts correctly?

Comment: yeah i saw that too, and as far as i know i am? i just downloaded it and linked it

Answer (score 1):

You need to include jQuery before bootstrap.

Comment: oh duh. thanks.. any ideas on why the padding is weird when the screen gets smaller?

Comment: http://www.easyuniv.com/staging/css/eStyle.css line 8 `#mainback` -> `width: 100%;
padding-left: 5%;` = `105%`, that's why, lower the width value to `95%` and the bottom scrollbar should go away. Cheers.

Comment: oh thats awesome i didn't really notice that before, i was referring to the ~10px gap on the left right and top when the screen is shrunk down

Comment: As far as i looked around it's because of the bootstrap `@media` queries, here's an example: `@media (max-width: 767px)
body {
padding-right: 20px;
padding-left: 20px;
}` and also the header gets a touch up: `@media (max-width: 979px)
.navbar-fixed-top .navbar-inner, .navbar-fixed-bottom .navbar-inner {
padding: 5px;
}`